# How to access index 5 in the dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-science, data-analysis

I have the data of dictionary:

```
mydict = {
    'K93': [((1200, 1, 'K93', 'AMK2FJVGB', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]), 
            ((1200, 1, 'K93', 'AMK2FJSRM', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]), 
            ((1200, 2, 'K93', 'AMK2FJVGB', 0.0, 600.0, 300), [300, 15]), 
            ((1200, 3, 'K93', 'AMK2FJABK', 0.125, 800.0, 400), [300, 15]), 
            ((1200, 2, 'K93', 'AMK2FJJBM', 0.6666666666666666, 900.0, 600), [300, 15]), 
            ((1200, 3, 'K93', 'AMK2FJJBM', 0.6666666666666666, 900.0, 600), [300, 15]), 
            ((1200, 1, 'K93', 'AMK2FJNBK', 0.0, 800.0, 400), [300.0, 15])], 
    'K0JA': [((1200, 1, 'K0JA', 'AMK0JA  ', 0.6, 700.0, 400), [600, 30]), 
            ((1200, 3, 'K0JA', 'AMK0JA  ', 0.0, 700.0, 400), [300, 15])], 

}
```

i want to access index 5 every key in the dictionary like this:

```
600
600
600
...
700
```

This is my current code:

```
for key,val in mydict.items():
    print(mydict[key][0][5])
```

Answer (score 0):

The values of the dictionary are themselves array, so you need another loop to iterate over them.

With this and a couple of other adjustments, you can do something like this:

```
for lst in mydict.values():  # .values() as you don't need the key
  for tpl, _ in lst:         # tpl, _ get first value and ignore the second
    print(tpl[5])            # you are already at the tuple level
```

When you get more familiarized with the language, you will see that in python you can express this kind of operation in a very short and straightforward fashion. For example, using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and the [star operator](https://python.plainenglish.io/star-or-asterisk-and-kwargs-or-args-in-python-94c4320f87b1).

```
print(*(t[5] for l in mydict.values() for t,_ in l), sep='\n')
```